# AngularJS, $cookieStore.put is not a function

Tags: angularjs, cookiestore

I am getting error - "$cookieStore.put is not a function when I am trying to save cookies in my app. I am using AngularJS 1.4.1 and cookies same ver.

```
var examinationApp = angular.module("examinationApp", ['ngCookies']);
examinationApp.controller("examinationCtrl", ['$scope', '$window', '$http',
'$interval','$cookieStore', function ($scope, $window, $http, $cookieStore,
modalDialog){
$scope.saveTestsToCookieStore = function () {
            $cookieStore.put('answeredTests',JSON.stringify($scope.data));
            $cookieStore.put('answeredQuestions',JSON.stringify($scope.answeredTests));
            $cookieStore.put('questionStopped',$scope.currentQN);
        }...
```

When I try to save cookies I an get error - TypeError: $cookieStore.put is not a function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameters aren't lining up...

Compare your list of dependencies in the inline array annotation to the list of parameters in the function declaration.  The lists of dependencies have to line up (same dependencies in the same order).  (Basically, your controller function was trying to call `put` on `$interval` rather than on `$cookieStore`)

What you have...

```
examinationApp.controller("examinationCtrl", [
  '$scope', '$window', '$http', '$interval','$cookieStore', 
  function ($scope, $window, $http, $cookieStore, modalDialog) {
```

What you need...

```
examinationApp.controller("examinationCtrl", [
  '$scope', '$window', '$http', '$cookieStore', 'modalDialog', 
  function ($scope, $window, $http, $cookieStore, modalDialog) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Angularjs >= 1.3

> The $cookieStore service is deprecated. Please use the $cookies
>   service instead.

You should use [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) to read/write access to browser's cookies.

Answer (score 0):

**Angular version == 1.3.5** , Suppose header value has been set "X-AUTH-TOKEN = '*eyJwYXNzd29yZCI6ImFkbWlu*'" in Application Security class after authentication.

```
$scope.postData = "{\"username\" : username , \"password\": password ,\"email\" :email}";

$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/API/authenticate',
            data: postData,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "X-Login-Ajax-call": 'true'
            }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.data == 'ok') {
                $cookies['X-AUTH-TOKEN']=response.headers('X-AUTH-TOKEN');
                window.location.replace('/');
            }
            else {

                // Error Message...
            }
        });
```